# query parameters cannot be retrieved from request header

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, servlets, http-headers

I am reading a book [Java Web Services](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zamJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=query%20string%20data%20encapsulated%20in%20http%20request%20header&source=bl&ots=YCpMQYmZM-&sig=wUAiN3BctFa-8MDFZSf2acoYDJ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ugMEVcjFMtCzuASJ2ICoAg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=query%20string%20data%20encapsulated%20in%20http%20request%20header&f=false) .I have found a statement as

```
query string data encapsulated in http request header in GET
```

What I understood from it is:

(1)Get request has no body, it only contains header part

(2)While sending data in GET , you can use query string

Now I am clear with these concepts.But I want to confirm it with code.

I have a controller in Spring MVC where I am sending a request like

http://localhost:8080/test?abc=1

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(HttpServletRequest req) {

    String abc1 = req.getHeader("abc");
    String abc2 = req.getParameter("abc");
    return "login";
}
```

abc1 is null

abc2 is "1"

So according the above statement I should get abc1 as "1".

Can somebody explain me the reason  why query parameters cannot be retrieved from header when they are sent in header part ?

Comment: Query parameters form part of the URL, as a collection of key value pairs. They are not part of the HTTP header. I think it would be clearer if the word header was removed from the sentence you have quoted.

Answer (score 1):

As @JamesB mentioned in comment, function HttpServletRequest.getHeader is for retrieving HTTP headers. It is not the same thing as request parameter. So getParameter is method that retrieves query parameters. You experienced that in your second statement.

BUT, I SEE THERE BROADER PROBLEM.
You should not use low level servlet APIs when you are using Spring MVC.
Use Spring Constructs instead:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@RequestParam("abc") int abc) {
    //use abc
    return "login";
}
```